# Spring custom validation message

Tags: spring, validation

Custom validation messages don't work. I have a domain class:

```
...
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Letter {

@NotNull(message="{validation.number_empty}")
@Size(min=1,max=20, message="{validation.number_size}")
@Column(length=20, nullable=false)
private String number;
...
}
```

/WEB-INF/i18n/messages.properties:

```
 #validation
 validation.number_size=number must be more than 1 and less than 20 symbols
 ...
```

I want to validate some fields from that domain class during form submitting. Validation works, but I get the output message:

**{validation.number_size}**

Instead of expected string: **number must be more than 1 and less than 20 symbols**
In other places of my project I use messages from properties files with success.

/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml

```
 <bean     
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" 
    id="messageSource" 
    p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages,WEB-INF/i18n/application" 
    p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false">
 </bean>
```

Also, I’ve tried , but without success:

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
     <property name="locations">
       <list>
         <value>classpath:WEB-INF/i18n/messages</value>
       </list>
     </property>
     <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
     <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need some additional config to customize the error messages using your messageSource.

Try following:

/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml:

```
...

<bean id="validator"
  class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
  <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource" />
</bean>
```

In your Controller class:

```
...

import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

...

@Autowired
private Validator validator;

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
  binder.setValidator(validator);
}
```

See [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation) section of the reference manual for details.

Comment: it saved me a day. This problem was without any Exceptions. How do you solve this problem? Are you always read documentation or you read source code of Spring framework or somthing else?

Comment: I usually check the official documentation first, then search the web.

Comment: Will Valid work for a RequestBody POJO that is not annotated with @component i.e just a simply wrapper class?